# ORA-12705 when using "empty" default locale and driver 10.2.0.4

Tags: java, oracle, driver, locale, ora-12705

I just found out that creating a connection to Oracle using JDBC Thin driver version 10.2.0.4 fails when the Locale is set to empty string, for example :

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("",""));
DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

The above code will produce ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified.
It works fine if I specify en US, or just en.

But if I use Oracle driver 9.2.0.1, this exact piece of code works : the NLS is set to AMERICAN.

My question is : Is this a normal, documented, change of behavior ?
Maybe setting default locale to empty strings is a bad practice ?

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to oracle support, note 115001.1 seems to state there are changes around this from 10g onwards:

> 9i Thick JDBC (=OCI) driver will make use of the NLS_LANG to determine
>   the how to convert characters. NOT defining the NLS_LANG will make
>   this to use the default US7ASCII setting, any non-ASCII data from /to
>   the database will be lost.
>
> You don't need to specify anything to your Java code for JDBC to pick
>   up the NLS_LANG.
>
> From 10g onwards the Thick JDBC driver is ignoring the NLS_LANG and
>   uses Language, Territory and characterset settings from the JVM
>   locale.
>
> In 11g the property -Doracle.jdbc.ociNlsLangBackwardCompatible=true is
>   settable on the command. If set it causes JDBC to get the characterset
>   from NLS_LANG instead of getting the client characterset id from the
>   locale.
>
> Language and territory are taken from the locale regardless of the
>   property though.

Comment: Thanks for your input.
But in this case I am referring to the thin driver, which does not rely on a NLS_LANG variable, only on the JVM locale if I am correct.
I have edited my question to specify I am talking about Thin driver.